# Is it a wise decision if I switch companies with higher base salary but higher cost of living?

Tags: salary, job-offer, software-development, cost-of-living

For the last 6 months, I've been a full stack developer in a small company that pays quite poorly. But I live with my parents, so I don't really have much financial responsibilities.

I was offered a 75% increase in salary from another company which is far from my parents house. I would have to rent and pay for my own food. I calculated the increase in my salary would only go to rent and food. All-in-all, I would make roughly the net pay at the new company as my current company.

**Facts from current company:**

```
1. Full stack Java web-developer (but i want to focus on back-end JAVA)

2. With Healthcard
3. Low salary. Based from long term employees, the increase in salary is very low. I would not get the 75% increase in 5years in my
current company. 
4. I travel 2 hours back and forth from my parents house. So total of 4 hours every day of travel.
5. I live with my niece and nephews, and other siblings in my parents house (which is fun) but i eat and sleep when i get home
6. I depend mostly on our maid to cook meals.
```

**Facts from company the offered:**

```
1. Back-End java developer (which is my passion)
2. Same healthcard
3. Increase in salary is 75%. Promotion and increase in salary yearly is still unknown to me. 
4. I would only travel 10-20 minutes everyday. Can bike to work. 
5. I Would still go home to my parents house every weekends.
6. I will be independent, will have to learn to cook for myself. But i wont be alone, I'm staying with my cousin and he gave me a really
good deal on rent.
7. I might have time to accept outside projects since my work is nearby the place im staying.
```

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace! This type of question you're asking is on a specific choice. We can't make the decision for you as to what the best option will be for your situation. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: If i was in your place I would move to new company.

Comment: @newguy simple comments like that would actually help me decide as i'm already losing my mind

Comment: I would also pick the higher salary and living independently. But are you ready to cook and clean for yourself?

Comment: @jcmack I really hope i am and i'm trying to look at this positively, being independent would teach me a lot of real life stuff. Its the actually the savings that concerns me. THanks for the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *want* to be independent and move from home, then the choice is clear: by your own account, your salary increase will go towards rent and food, but you will be working closer to your passion and future salary opportunities may be better at your new company than at your current. So your position would be strictly better by taking the move. And by the way, cooking isn't hard. Pick up a few recipe books (or watch videos online). It can be quite fun.

Of course, if you *don't want* to move away from home, then it is a different matter, and in that case, we can't make judgement for you, because to be with family is a precious thing that doesn't compare directly to the work life. You will have to balance the two and decide for yourself.